# SQL запрос как связать две таблицы не используя ключ

Tags: sql, запрос, таблицы

Есть две таблицы:

Первая таблица:

| Country | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Russia | 710 |

Вторая таблица:

| People | Phone |
| --- | --- |
| Oleg | 79171157 |

Как обьединить эти таблицы по первой цифре из обеих таблиц (первая таблица по столбцу: Code):
(вторая таблица по столбцу: Phone) таким образом цифра= 7 является сцепкой(связующей для них)

Comment: `ON LEFT(table1.code, 1) = LEFT(table2.phone, 1)`

Comment: спасибо Вам !!!